# ViewDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/ (django-registration-me error)

Tags: django, django-registration, mongoengine

I am currently working on a project which uses mongoengine and django. I am using django-registration-me to handle user registrations, but I am having problems after submitting the new user registration form.

The error I am receiving is:

> "ViewDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/" "Tried settings in module
>   core.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'settings'"

It sends a verification email out fine though. I am new to django and mongoengine, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The traceback is below.

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
>   http://dev.teamfit.us:8000/accounts/register/
>
> Django Version: 1.3 beta 1 SVN-15207
>
> Python Version: 2.6.6
>
> Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.sites', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',
>   'registration']
>
> Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/usr/src/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request,
>   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_registration_me-0.7-py2.6.egg/registration/views.py"
>   in register
>     153.             return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url or
>   reverse('registration_complete'))
>
> File
>   "/usr/src/django-trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
>   in reverse
>     390.             *args, **kwargs)))
>
> File
>   "/usr/src/django-trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
>   in reverse
>     311.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
>
> File
>   "/usr/src/django-trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
>   in _get_reverse_dict
>     228.             self._populate()
>
> File
>   "/usr/src/django-trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
>   in _populate
>     219.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback,
>   (bits, p_pattern))
>
> File
>   "/usr/src/django-trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
>   in _get_callback
>     169.             raise ViewDoesNotExist("Tried %s in module
>   %s. Error was: %s" % (func_name,
>   mod_name, str(e)))
>
> Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at
>   /accounts/register/
>
> Exception Value: Tried settings in
>   module core.views. Error was: 'module'
>   object has no attribute 'settings'

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have

import settings

or some such variation in your code.

You should change it to:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

and it should work